# Android app crashes on start of new activity

Tags: android

I gave up on this app some time ago because this app started crashing for some reason.  Now that I'm back at it, I removed all the code expect what needs to be there to start the second activity.
Activity 1(below): Read some data and put it in an SQL database on a button click.  This method runs until the end as is.
Activity 2(DatabaseList.class): Display SQL database.

Long story short: I removed a bunch of code to reproduce the crash with as little code as possible.
Debug: Debugger hangs after placeInDB() finishes in AppCompat.java or something.
Run: App crashes

```
public void placeInDB(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Everything aside, I should at least see the debugger move into DatabaseList, right?  Again, I see no errors or warnings.

Comment: share error logs

Comment: show where you call the method placeIndb(v v)

Comment: Hello, I don't see any errors and the method is called via the 'onClick' attribute of a button in the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the stack trace, following are the possible causes of failure.

- `DatabaseList` may not be an activity.
- `DatabaseList` might not have been defined as an activity inside the manifest file.
- The activity might be the subclass of `AppCompatActivity` and you have not used `AppCompat` theme.